# scroll to the relevant item on html after serving a server call

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am rendering a html page with a list of things with an option to edit any one of them.

Draft:

[image]

On clicking on any of the item, makes a server call and effectively an update in the database.

Now, What i want to do is, When the list is long and the page is scrolled all the way to the bottom (for eg. ITEM 1000) and the user makes any server request,

after the page is reloaded, the user should be scrolled down at the exact item. Is this possible?

What is a good way to approach this functionality?

I am aware of anchor tag and name attribute and then posting `url.com/#anchorTagName`. But in case of server call, we dont provide any urls, its just a form.submit

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sending sending the request via AJAX? Can you show an Example?

Comment: You don't have to post a URL to send the user to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tag is the best approach `url.com/#anchorTagName` but as you said the server doesn't provide it.

Here are some other alternatives:

**1. Session attribute:**

Once the server call is made and the data is loaded successfully in the DB, set a session variable. (session variable will contain tag)

In the UI using scriplet, assign the session variable to a javascript variable.

Now on page load, let the javascript to get the variable and scroll to the particular location.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
    var scrollNow = "#<%=session.getAttribute('')%>"
    window.location.href = scrollNow; // this will take to the particular element based on the ID
   }
</script>
```

Another option, is to append the location in query string. Same way get the location and let the javascript do its part just like before :)

**Another option,**

In the form submit, handle the event via javascript before submitting the form.

Construct the action url dynamically with the hash tag and send it to the server.

So when the server receives it, it will ignore the anchor tag and will process the data.

When the page refershes again, the page scroll to the previous location as the anchor tag will be there in the URL :)